# Node.js header error after TCP connection lost

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm new to `Node.js` and I'm using [this library](https://github.com/respectTheCode/node-caspar-cg) to connect to a `CasparCG server` (TCP connection). Now, I'm trying to create some type of error handling and I have a two part question.

I connect normally and my UI gives indication that a connection has been established. Then for testing purposes I restart the server resulting in connection lost. I get this message in my console:

```
_http_outgoing.js:335
throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
      ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
at ServerResponse.header (C:\www\node-    test\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:718:10)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\www\node-test\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:163:12)
at ServerResponse.json (C:\www\node-test\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:249:15)
at null.<anonymous> (C:\www\node-test\api\caspar.js:33:44)
at emit (events.js:104:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\www\node-test\node_modules\caspar-cg\lib\connection.js:60:9)
at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:991:10)
Program node server.js exited with code 1
```

**Route:**

```
var CasparCG = require('caspar-cg');
var ccg = new CasparCG("192.168.1.100", 5250);

var _cg_connected = false;

ccg.on('connected', function () {
    _cg_connected = true;
});

ccg.on('error', function (error) {
    _cg_connected = false;
    console.log(error);
});

ccg.on('connectionError', function (error) {
    _cg_connected = false;
    console.log(error);
});

ccg.on('end', function () {
    _cg_connected = false;
    console.log('Connection ended');
});

ccg.on('close', function () {
    _cg_connected = false;
    console.log('Connection closed');
});

module.exports = function(router, connection) {
router.post('/casparcg/connect', function(req, res) {
    if(_cg_connected) {
        return res.status(200).json({success: true, message: 'Connection already established'});
    }

    ccg.connect(function () {
         if(_cg_connected) {
            return res.status(200).json({success: true, message: 'Connection established'});
        } else {
            return res.status(503).json({success: false, message: 'Connection failed'});
        }
    });
});
```

}

Now how can I actually capture this 'Connection lost' error or whatever without it resulting in a crash and restart?

**My second question:**

My app uses node.js as a REST API in front of AngularJS. Can I create some type of listener to AngularJS where it captures node.js sending a message "We've lost connection. Letting you know" and AngularJS can adapt appropriately in this case meaning I can switch off a variable `connection = false` and set buttons accordingly.

**Edit:**

Discovered a fault in the code. Moved all TCP 'on' listeners outside the route only leaving connect(callback) there. It now reconnects on restart automatically, but logs an error on total disconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does the following:

- handling a POST request to `/casparcg/connect`
- inside your handler, you're establishing a new connection and reacting to various events that could occur over time (maybe minutes after the initial request)
- but an HTTP request can be answered only once
- when your code runs through the initial `connect` event, it will reply to the POST request with a 200 status code
- later, when an event is received (like an error), it will try to answer that same request **again**... which will not work because "headers have already been sent" (ie the client is long gone).

So the problem is one of logic. You're trying to establish a long running request (to detect disconnections) BUT you **answer** the request when a connect is established... you can't change your mind and send "oops disconnected" later, because the reply was already sent.

Also, it's probably a bad idea to establish a new connection just to detect a drop of THAT connection... Your app will need another connection to do real stuff with it, I guess.

If you really need a "session/connected design", then switch to WebSockets, ajax/REST won't cut it. Websockets allow a statefull design, where a connection is established, can be monitored on both sides, and where any number of messages can be sent between client and server, in any order.
If you don't want to use websockets, you'll end up implementing a poor man's websockets anyway...

Also I don't know what `ccg` is, but it looks like you connect to it without arguments... so the connection doesn't really depend on the user who's connected... Maybe you could establish a single connection for all your users? or maybe use a pool of `n` connections to serve `N` clients, where `n < N`... and avoid wasting connections, and connection latency...

Comment: You're right. I actually adjusted the code moving the .on() functions outside the route because they don't need to be "re-established". The connect route now only attempts to connect and just returns true if it's already connected. It now reconnects when restarted and doesn't crash when I shut down the server. It logs a timeout but can I somehow capture that and send it to Angular?

Comment: Yes, thanks! that actually was the solution.I already got it working.